# I'm getting the same ip address from different computers in same network

Tags: php, ip-address

I'm trying to get the ip address of the client so that they only use one account per device.
However, when I use the following code, I found that the same ip address returned from the computers in the same network.

```php
function get_client_ip() {
        $ipaddress = '';
        if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
            $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
        else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
            $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
        else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED'))
            $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');
        else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'))
            $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');
        else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED'))
            $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');
        else if(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'))
            $ipaddress = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
        else
            $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';

        return $ipaddress;
    }
```

How can I get the correct ip address from different devices?

Comment: PHP can't really detect the local IP, as its serverside code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely those computers are going from network through the router with `NAT` enabled.
In that case you will see only ip address of that router, nothing you can do with it.

But you can check combination of ip address and user-agent header:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
```

Unfortunately, there is no garaunteed way to 100% check the origin of request, but combination of ip address and user-agent could work for simple scenario.